# CSS - Ajuste de líneas con palabras largas y sin espacios que superan el ancho del contenedor

Tags: html, css

Tengo el siguiente código:

```css
.mensajes{
 width: 100%;
 text-align: right;
 border: 2px solid lightgray;
 font-size: 16px!important;
}
.block{
 display: block;
}
.margin-x-20{
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.mensajes .sideR{
   display: table-cell;
}
.contenedor{
 min-width: 30%!important;
}

.mensajes .sideR .contenedor{
 float: right;
 text-align: right;
 border-radius: 7px;
 border: 2px solid #337ab7;
 max-width: 70%;
 padding: 4px 10px;
 margin-right: 25px; 
 position: relative;
}
.mensajes .sideR .contenedor .boton{
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-left: 10px solid #337ab7;
 border-top: 10px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
 position: absolute;
 right: -10px;
 bottom: 5px;
}
.mensajes .sideD{
   display: table-cell;
}
.mensajes .sideD .contenedor{
 float: left;
 text-align: left;
 border-radius: 7px;
 border: 2px solid #337ab7;
 max-width: 70%;
 padding: 4px 10px;
 margin-left: 25px; 
 position: relative;
}
.mensajes .sideD .contenedor .boton{
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-right: 10px solid #337ab7;
 border-top: 10px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
 position: absolute;
 left: -10px;
 bottom: 5px;
}

.contenedor .insider{
 position: relative;
}

.contenedor .text{
 word-wrap: break-word;
 white-space:normal;
  /*word-break:break-all;*/
}

.contenedor .pie{
 width: 100%;
 border-top: 1px solid #337ab7;
 font-size: 13px!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="mensajes">
  <div class="block margin-x-20">
   <div class="sideR">
    <div class="contenedor">
     <div class="boton"></div>
     <div class="insider">
      <div class="seen"></div>
      <div class="text"> asdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasd klfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsf sdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsd asdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfs fsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsd
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="pie block text-center">
      21/01/2017 02:22am
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block margin-x-20">
   <div class="sideD">
    <div class="contenedor">
     <div class="boton"></div>
     <div class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
      consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
      cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
      proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laboru
     </div>
     <div class="pie block text-center">
      21/01/2017 02:22am
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Al haber un texto **demasiado** largo y sin espacios, se mueve de su lugar (se sale del contenedor **mensajes**).
En cambio si el texto es largo pero tiene espacios, funciona correctamente.

> No quiero usar `word-break: break-all` porque si hay texto normal con espacios, lo "parte". Y **sólo quiero que haga eso con la palabra larga sin espacios**. Como lo es el siguiente ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Anchos fijos**

El motivo por el cual `word-wrap` no te funciona es porque el ancho del contenedor es dinámico.
Si fuese fijo, funcionaría bien.

```css
.text {
    border: 1px solid orangered;
    
    width: 300px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
Línea con una palabra extremadamenteLargaYLuego una línea muy larga sin espacios: asdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsffsfsdasdklfsfs
</div>
```

> **Nota:** esta propiedad [fue renombrada a `overflow-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap) y, con anchos fijos, recomendaría usar:
>
> ```css
> overflow-wrap: break-word;
> ```

**Anchos dinámicos**

Esta solución se basa en [hyphens](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/hyphens) como la principal forma de separar en sílabas cuando es necesario cortar una palabra, y depende del diccionario incluido por la propiedad `lang` de la etiqueta `<html>`. Sin embargo no funciona en Chrome, por lo que usamos `word-break: break-word`, una propiedad no estándar, que no está documentada, pero funciona en WebKit con anchos dinámicos:

```css
.text {
    -ms-word-break: break-all;
    word-break: break-all;
    word-break: break-word;     /* Sólo WebKit -NO DOCUMENTADO */

    -ms-hyphens: auto;          /* Guiones para separar en sílabas */
    -moz-hyphens: auto;         /*  depende de lang en <html>      */
    -webkit-hyphens: auto;
    hyphens: auto;
}
```

<sup>**Funciona en Chrome 13, FF 6, Safari 5.1, iOS 4.2, IE 8.**</sup>

Demo:

```css
.mensajes {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  border: 2px solid lightgray;
  font-size: 16px!important;
}
.block {
  display: block;
}
.margin-x-20 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.mensajes .sideR {
  display: table-cell;
}
.contenedor {
  min-width: 30%!important;
}
.mensajes .sideR .contenedor {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
  border-radius: 7px;
  border: 2px solid #337ab7;
  max-width: 70%;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  margin-right: 25px;
  position: relative;
}
.mensajes .sideR .contenedor .boton {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid #337ab7;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  right: -10px;
  bottom: 5px;
}
.mensajes .sideD {
  display: table-cell;
}
.mensajes .sideD .contenedor {
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 7px;
  border: 2px solid #337ab7;
  max-width: 70%;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  position: relative;
}
.mensajes .sideD .contenedor .boton {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-right: 10px solid #337ab7;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  left: -10px;
  bottom: 5px;
}
.contenedor .insider {
  position: relative;
}
.contenedor .text {
  -ms-word-break: break-all;
  word-break: break-all;
  word-break: break-word;
  /* Sólo WebKit -NO DOCUMENTADO */
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  /* Guiones para separar en sílabas */
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  /*  depende de lang en <html>      */
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
}
.contenedor .pie {
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid #337ab7;
  font-size: 13px!important;
}
```

```html
<html lang="es">
<div class="mensajes">
  <div class="block margin-x-20">
    <div class="sideR">
      <div class="contenedor">
        <div class="boton"></div>
        <div class="insider">
          <div class="seen"></div>
          <div class="text">
            Línea normal con una palabra que puede ser extremadamenteLargaQueSe ajusta bien. Además, con palabras más largas que la línea, pasa esto: asdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdalfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfs
            asdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdalfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfs
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pie block text-center">
          21/01/2017 02:22am
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block margin-x-20">
    <div class="sideD">
      <div class="contenedor">
        <div class="boton"></div>
        <div class="text">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laboru
        </div>
        <div class="pie block text-center">
          21/01/2017 02:22am
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: No me va muy bien con hyphens, debo entonces pasar a anchos "fijos" controlados por JQuery para que sean dinámicos en sí.